# how do i add this section of code that was suggessted by another user?

Tags: ios, swift

here is my original code first:

```
        import UIKit

class CalculatorViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var firstButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var secondButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var thirdButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var fourthButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var fifthButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var nextPageButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var firstTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var secondTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var thirdTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var fourthTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var fifthTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

var firstButtonDataSource = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
var secondButtonDataSource = ["White", "Red", "Green", "Blue"];
var thirdButtonDataSource = ["Mike", "Steve", "Ben", "Peter"];
var fourthButtonDataSource = ["Large", "Medium", "Small", "Extra-small"];
var fithButtonDataSource = ["USA", "UK", "France", "Germany"];

var lastPressedButton: UIButton?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    firstButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    secondButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    thirdButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    fourthButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    fifthButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    self.pickerView.dataSource = self;
    self.pickerView.delegate = self;
}

@objc func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton!) {

    lastPressedButton = sender

    if lastPressedButton == firstButton {
        firstTextField.inputView = pickerView
    } else if lastPressedButton == secondButton {
        secondTextField.inputView = pickerView
    } else if lastPressedButton == thirdButton {
        thirdTextField.inputView = pickerView
    } else if lastPressedButton == fourthButton {
        fourthTextField.inputView = pickerView
    } else if lastPressedButton == fifthButton {
        fifthTextField.inputView = pickerView
    }
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if lastPressedButton == firstButton {
        return firstButtonDataSource.count;
    } else if lastPressedButton == secondButton {
        return secondButtonDataSource.count;
    } else if lastPressedButton == thirdButton {
        return thirdButtonDataSource.count;
    } else if lastPressedButton == fourthButton {
        return fourthButtonDataSource.count;
    } else if lastPressedButton == fifthButton {
        return fithButtonDataSource.count;
    }

    return 0
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if lastPressedButton == firstButton {
        return firstButtonDataSource[row];
    } else if lastPressedButton == secondButton {
        return secondButtonDataSource[row];
    } else if lastPressedButton == thirdButton {
        return thirdButtonDataSource[row];
    } else if lastPressedButton == fourthButton {
        return fourthButtonDataSource[row];
    } else if lastPressedButton == fifthButton {
        return fithButtonDataSource[row];
    }

    return ""
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if lastPressedButton == firstButton {
        self.firstTextField.text = firstButtonDataSource[row]
    } else if lastPressedButton == secondButton {
        self.secondTextField.text = secondButtonDataSource[row]
    } else if lastPressedButton == thirdButton {
        self.thirdTextField.text = thirdButtonDataSource[row]
    } else if lastPressedButton == fourthButton {
        self.fourthTextField.text = fourthButtonDataSource[row]
    } else if lastPressedButton == fifthButton {
        self.fifthTextField.text = fithButtonDataSource[row]
    }
}
}
```

Then here is what I was told to do:

"
It looks like you never set the correct text field as the first responder.

BTW, all your long if/else if/else if... constructs would be cleaner as switch statements, or you could even set up dictionaries with the buttons as the key and then a struct containing the data source and the picker view for that button:"

```
     struct ButtonData {
let buttonDataSource: [String]
let buttonTextField: UITextField
}

let buttonsDict = [
firstButton: ButtonData(buttonDataSource: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
                        buttonTextField: firstTextField),
secondButton: ButtonData(buttonDataSource: ["White", "Red", "Green", "Blue"],
                         buttonTextField: secondTextField),
thirdButton: ButtonData(buttonDataSource: ["Mike", "Steve", "Ben", "Peter"],
                        buttonTextField: thirdTextField),
fourthButton: ButtonData(buttonDataSource: ["Large", "Medium", "Small", "Extra-small"],
                         buttonTextField: fourthTextField),
fifthButton: ButtonData(buttonDataSource: ["USA", "UK", "France", "Germany"],
                        buttonTextField: fifthTextField)
]
```

AND THEn he said: "And then code like your button action could use the dictionary:"

```
    @objc func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton!) {

lastPressedButton = sender

guard let buttonStruct = buttonsDict[lastPressedButton] else { return }

let textField = buttonsStruct.buttonTextField

textField.inputView = pickerView

//I think this the code you need to show the picker
textField.becomeFirstResponder() 
}
```

so my question is how to add these two new groups of code to my original code and update it? I have tried numerous methods and places but I am not experienced enough in code to be able to not mess something up in my project

Comment: Separate class file for Struct

Comment: let buttonsDict = [...,...,  ...,..., ], in ur viewcontroller

Comment: @objc func buttonClicked , replace ur logic with his logic.

Comment: can u please just add it in together in a playground please?

Comment: idk who downvoted u i dont have enough karma to do that but i guess they thought it was wrong, i cant understand your instructions sorry

Comment: U have to add that new code in ur existing code right ?

Comment: Voting to close. If you have an answer to a previous question that helped and you have no clue how to implement, why (a) accept the answer then (b) create a new one about implementing it? Haven't **yet** down voted, but yeah, *"learn what this site is about", "learn how to ask good questions"*... I can go on more BUT... tis site is about helping others - both you *and* those who see this question. (BTW, I spent rep points voting the only answer - it claims to be helpful but contains screenshots and doesn't really *explain* how it's an answer.)

Comment: Did u read the quest ? He is having code with him. he dont knw how to add. So I show the screenshot.

Answer (score -1):

This image will helpful. This `Red mark` is for `UIPickerViewDelegate`.

Create empty `Swift` file named `ButtonData` and copy this code.

In `ViewController`, you can try like this.

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var secondButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var thirdButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var fourthButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var fifthButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var firstTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var secondTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var thirdTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var fourthTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var fifthTextField: UITextField!


var buttonsDict = [UIButton : ButtonData]()
var lastPressedButton: UIButton?
@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    buttonsDict = [
        firstButton: ButtonData(buttonDataSource: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
                                buttonTextField: firstTextField),
        secondButton: ButtonData(buttonDataSource: ["White", "Red", "Green", "Blue"],
                                 buttonTextField: secondTextField),
        thirdButton: ButtonData(buttonDataSource: ["Mike", "Steve", "Ben", "Peter"],
                                buttonTextField: thirdTextField),
        fourthButton: ButtonData(buttonDataSource: ["Large", "Medium", "Small", "Extra-small"],
                                 buttonTextField: fourthTextField),
        fifthButton: ButtonData(buttonDataSource: ["USA", "UK", "France", "Germany"],
                                buttonTextField: fifthTextField)
    ]

    firstButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    secondButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    thirdButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    fourthButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    fifthButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    self.pickerView.dataSource = self;
    self.pickerView.delegate = self;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@objc func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton!) {

    lastPressedButton = sender

    guard let buttonStruct = buttonsDict[lastPressedButton!] else { return }

    let textField = buttonStruct.buttonTextField

    textField.inputView = pickerView

    //I think this the code you need to show the picker
    textField.becomeFirstResponder() 
}


// STRUCT
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct ButtonData {
    let buttonDataSource: [String]
    let buttonTextField: UITextField
}
```

[image]

Comment: No, images of code are not helpful. Please replace this image with the actual code, as text.